# I am getting target class does not exist error in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

The routing process has changed in Laravel version 8. I did as in the internet but it gives an error. Where am I doing wrong?

**Route file**

```
<?php
        
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
        use App\Http\Controllers\Backend\BackendHomeController;
        
        Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('welcome');
        });
        
        Route::get('/admin', [BackendHomeController::class, 'index'])->name("index");
```

**Controller file**

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    class HomeController extends Controller
    {
        public static function index()
        {
            return view("backend.index");
        }
    }
```

`BackendHomeController` also like this. Everything seems to be correct, but am I doing something wrong with using?

Error says

> target class does not exist error

Comment: can you mention error also .so some one can help you better way

Comment: I am getting target class does not exist error

Comment: can you post BackendHomeController also

Comment: it should be Route::get('/admin', [HomeController ::class, 'index'])->name("index"); and import  as    use App\Http\Controllers\Backend\HomeController;

Comment: The name of the class is wrong... `HomeController` versus `BackendHomeController`.

Comment: A sane IDE will warn you if the class name is different from the filename of the class. Use a good IDE.

Comment: you are right, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class is referenced as `BackendHomeController` but your file is named `HomeController`. These should align for autoloading to be working.